# I recently deleted all versions of python from my laptop. However when I click on the windows icon, I can still see the python 3.10 folder

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

When I right click on it to unistall it, it opens the control panel but there is no python 3.10 file in the list of installed programs. I am very confused. Is python downloaded in my laptop or not? And why is that folder still showing when i click on windows icon

I have tried to uninstall it but it is not present in the control panel/programs and features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `python` in your computer then right click it and click "Open File Location" (It can be on `More` menu if it's not there). If its opens python shortcut's location which probably will, right click that shortcut and "Open File Location" again. Then delete all files.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You can mark it as the answer so it can help others too.